# Move to datagrid cell by passing row and column number

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid

I have row number and column number of each cell in datagrid now i want to pass row and column number and move to the spacfic cell of the grid in wpf vb.net

Comment: What have you tried? Show us the code you have tried. Explain why it didn't meet your requirements.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.